# Because your app depends on flutter_link_preview ^1.0.3 which depends on http ^0.12.1, http ^0.12.1 is required

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

**I have this problem when pub get my app**

> because flutter_twitter depends on flutter_link_preview ^1.0.3 which depends on http ^0.12.1, http ^0.12.1 is required"

**I try to change http ^0.13.0 to http ^0.12.1 but have this problem**

> Because google_fonts 2.1.0 depends on http ^0.13.0 and no versions of google_fonts match >2.1.0 <3.0.0, google_fonts ^2.1.0 requires http ^0.13.0

**this is pubspec:-**

```yaml
version: 1.0.6+11
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  dartz: ^0.9.2
  get_it: ^5.0.6
  freezed_annotation: ^0.12.0
  flutter_link_preview: ^1.0.3
  cached_network_image: ^3.1.0
  provider: ^4.3.2+2
  firebase_auth: ^2.0.0
  firebase_database:
  firebase_analytics:
  cloud_firestore:
  firebase_storage: 
  equatable: ^2.0.0
  http: ^0.12.1
  image_picker: ^0.8.2
  package_info: ^0.4.1
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.1+2
  firebase_messaging: ^10.0.3
  google_sign_in: "^4.5.1" 
  intl: ^0.17.0
  url_launcher:
  share: ^2.0.4
  google_fonts: ^2.1.0
  firebase_remote_config: ^0.10.0+2
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^2.0.6
  qr_code_scanner: ^0.3.5
  qr_flutter: ^3.2.0
  rxdart: ^0.27.1
```

Comment: Downgrade `google_fonts` aswell.

Answer (score 1):

flutter_link_preview: ^1.0.3 change into
flutter_link_preview:

Somtimes it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Update your library like this-

flutter_link_preview:
http:

if you still face any issue, you can remove all version from every library/packages. It will work in every case.

Answer (score 0):

This was shared by AlphaMerc(creator of Fwitter, Twitter clone) :
"Not really a good practice, but I managed to overcome the same situation by overriding the http dependency.

Add inside the pubspec.yaml file the following

dependency_overrides:
http: ^0.13.3"

I tried the above and it works.